# Cannot npn run sass

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

I am in folder `C:\Users\borka\Desktop\Courses\HTML & CSS (Traversy)\Sandbox\13_sass`, using a bash terminal in VSCode and npm version **6.14.8**.

I have successfully run `npm init -y` and `npm install node-sass`, then edited the **package.json** file to contain `"scripts": { "sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive" }`.

Then, I created a `scss` directory with `main.scss` inside, as well as a `dist` directory. And finally, I run `npm run sass`, but it fails and here's what I get:

```
> 13_sass@1.0.0 sass C:\Users\borka\Desktop\Courses\HTML & CSS (Traversy)\Sandbox\13_sass
> node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive

'CSS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\borka\Desktop\Courses\node-sass\bin\node-sass'    
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)       
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! 13_sass@1.0.0 sass: `node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the 13_sass@1.0.0 sass script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\borka\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-31T16_01_42_707Z-debug.log
```

Notice how the **Error: Cannot find module** line displays a totally wrong path, one that doesn't even exist.

I've never worked with sass before and I have no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make a comment yet, but I think that the package you are looking for to compile your SASS into CSS is [this one](https://sass-lang.com/install). I noticed your using `node-sass` instead of regular `sass`. You can install it by running:

```sh
npm install -g sass
```

To install it globally on your system, and then compile your SASS.

Try with the one I'm sharing, or, if your are using an IDE like VSCode, you can dowload an extension like [Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) (that's the one I normally use).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the ampersand in the path was the cause. I removed it from folder name "HTML & CSS", and now everything's fine.